# In Yahoo Mail, how can I search through folders?

Tags: search, yahoo-mail

I have a folder with 1000s of emails. I'm looking for a particular email from 2011 I *know* is in this folder. When I try to search, Yahoo automatically redirects to my inbox, and searches the inbox.

How can I search through folders?

Answer (score 3):

You can click the search field to get the drop-down to appear, then click "Advanced Search" which, among other things, gives you the option to search within a specific folder.

[image: advanced search menu]

Easier, though, might be to just use the `in:` search operator.

```
in:folder-name search terms
```

If your folder name has spaces in it, just enclose it in double-quotes:

```
in:"folder name" search terms
```